# Удалить все, кроме, последних 4 символов

Tags: php

Есть строка:

```
http://site.com/004/005/007/0058
```

Нужно убрать все кроме последних 4 символов. Подскажите как это можно сделать на PHP.

Comment: Странные люди минусуют вопрос, когда он вполне корректен, и также дан на него вполне корректный ответ. Если пользоваться Googl'ом конкретно такой задачи нигде не описывается. А тут она появилась, да еще и с решением.

Comment: А если будет `http://site.com/004/005/007/58`, то тоже последние 4 символа (`7/58`) нужно выбрать или всё-таки последнюю часть пути (`58`)?  А если `http://site.com/004/005/007/58123`? У вас *[абстракция протекает](http://russian.joelonsoftware.com/Articles/LeakyAbstractions.html)*: вы работаете с URLом, а обращаетесь с ним и задачу ставите как с обычной строкой.  Возможно, минусы из-за этого.

Comment: https://repl.it/MoOc/0

Comment: @Other во-первых, нужно как раз удалить всё до последнего слеша. Во-вторых, публикуйте ответ, плюсану.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, не то написал. Но исправился :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для php 5.6 и выше:

```
$s = 'http://site.com/004/005/007/0058';
$s = substr( $s, -4 );
```

Comment: Ваш вариант работает, спасибо большое, ставлю как решение так как меньше кода - это круто!

Comment: @I.Z. спасибо. Я посмотрел сейчас в документации. Вобщем, ошибочка есть. Этот код поддерживается с версии PHP _5.2.6_

Comment: @I.Z меньше кода, не значит лучше, в данном примере, нарушины все стандарты PSR, и правильное обьявления переменных. Не сказал бы, что это лучший код.

Comment: PHP 5.2.6 найти ещё надо постараться! Как вы это смогли? Тут для 5.3 все круги ада пройти приходится.

Comment: @sanmai я как-бы не фанат старых версий... но, если в спецификации написано 5.2.6, то, надеюсь, что оно так и есть. А там, поди пойми, какая версия у ТС... Предупрежден - значит вооружен

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = substr('http://site.com/004/005/007/0058', -4);
```

Данная функция, гуглится быстро, в следующий раз, постарайтесь найти решение сами.

Comment: Да, этот вариант работает при условии, что перед последними 4 символами именно 28 знаков. Однако не всегда все так идеально. Нужна выборка с конца, последние 4 символа из URL. Как это сделать?

Comment: Я обновил, отсчёт будет с конца. Это так же написано в оф документик

Comment: Да, спасибо, это сработает если URL будет именно таким как в примере.

Comment: @I.Z. Ну так это же пример, достаточный для демонстрации. Понятно, что в реальной работе любой догадается использовать переменную вместо константной строки. У вас знаете ли вопрос то же сформулирован "Есть строка такая то", а не "Есть переменная, содержащая такую то строку".

Comment: @Mike а вас тут не смутило, что с урлом обращаются как с простой строкой? Подозреваю, что суть задачи — не 4 символа из строки добыть, а последнюю часть пути из урла.

Answer (score 1):

Как [сказал @NickVolynkin](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/722031/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-4-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2?noredirect=1#comment1112518_722031) - у Вас, вероятно, утекла абстракция: необходимо работать с [указателем](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL), а не строкой, иначе неизбежны проблемы:

```
// Парсим URL
$url = parse_url('http://site.com/004/005/007/0058');

// Берём путь c последнего слеша
$url = basename($url['path']);

var_dump($url); // string(4) "0058"
```

---

Если всё-таки это строка и нужно отрезать именно 4 символа с конца, то [ответ уже есть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/722035/207618):

```
$s = 'http://site.com/004/005/007/0058';
$s = substr( $s, -4 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s = 'http://site.com/004/005/007/0058';
$s = substr($s, strlen($s) - 4);
```

Comment: Ваш вариант работает, но я не поставил его как решение, так как вариант Sergey Khomenko, использует меньше символов. Вам так же большое спасибо!